# Eclipse with PyDev error highlighting

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

Eclipse with PyDev has error highlighting in some strange places.
It detects an error on a function like this (it's an example from "A Byte of Python" about functions with `VarArgs`):

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers, extra_number=10):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    count += extra_number
    print(count)
```

The error detected is: `Expected:)` on the first line and `undefined variable: extra_number`. I think it doesn't understand parameters with keywords.

Also, when I try to use variables with the `nonlocal` word - I get an error: `undefined variable: nonlocal`.

How can I improve PyDev's error messages and turn off errors for those examples?

P.S. on `PyCharm` or `Komodo` I don't see those errors, but I like opensource `PyDev` so much.

Comment: i tried on my eclipse with PyDev its not showing any error highlight.. i have not changed any settings or preferences for error highlight

Comment: So strange. I refresh code analysis in PyDev and create new project with new interpreter - all okay i don't see errors too. But in old project i have this error. Maybe some bug be in project config or interpreter connection ... I don't know. Thank you for your testing. It helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well something tells me you are actually using `Python 2.x` and not `3.x` since both errors you specified would be present in `2.x` and not in `3.x`.

[Check your interpeter](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) in PyDev, you have probably set it to use `2.7`.

Comment: Thank you. I used python3.4 interpreter for this project. But when i deleted it and reconnect it again - all those errors was deleted.